# Changing height of UITableViewCell Dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to show comments of each User in my TableView. The comments can BE accommodated by an Image.

Usually We can set height of a UITableViewCell as heightForRowAtIndex. However I want each Cell to Expand according to the Chat And if Image included upto image height.

How can I increase the height of UITablViewCell as per its contents?

Comment: You can add new rows for the comments ... better than increasing row height ... you can even make each user in a section and his comments as a rows in that section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still going to have to do it in heightForRowAtIndex:, except that you'll have to dynamically determine the height.

I'm envisioning something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CommentModel *comment = self.comments[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height = [CommentTableViewCell heightForComment:comment];
    return height;
}
```

And then in your CommentTableViewCell, you have a class method that goes something like:

```
// Calculates the height a CommentTableViewCell should be when configured with the given comment
+ (CGFloat)heightForComment:(CommentModel *)comment {
    // This part of the code will be very specific to your own project
    CGFloat height = BASE_HEIGHT;
    height += comment.image.size.height;
    height += comment.message.size.height;
    return height;
}
```

I know that this code probably doesn't match your code base, but it should give you a general idea of one way your goal can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS CODE IF YOU DONT HAVE CUSTOM CELL CLASS.**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         float PADDING = 0.5f; // USE FOR DIFFERNCE BETWEEN YOUR ENDING TEXT AND SEPERATOR
         UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]; // Some Image you want to put dynamically.
         NSString *text = @"Sometext That you want tro fill Dynamically";

         CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(270 , 1000)];
         return ((textSize.height+image.size.height+ PADDING * 3) + 30);
}
```

**IF YOU HAVE CUSTOM CLASS THEN YOU HAVE TO PASS THE HIEGHT TO CUSTOM CELL TO MANAGE YOU LABEL HIEGHT SAME AS YOU EXPAND YOUR CELL OVERTHERE. YOU CAN DO IT SEPARATELY IN CELL CLASS BUT TO SYNCHRONIZE IT WITH YOUR ACTUAL HIEGHT F CELL. YOU HAVE TO PASS HIEGHT IN CUSTOM CLASS WHEN YOU WILL SETTING ITS VALUES.**

Comment: The problem is we will be setting Cell values in cellForRowAtIndex delegate function of TableView. But heightForRow get's called first. How can i MANAGE This.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Hopefully you're not trying to dynamically change the height in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you have a reasonable design, it should be trivial to get the same data that you're using to set the cell data in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and use it to calculate the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath:. I recommended putting the calculation code in a separate View class to keep unrelated logic separated.